# Using pointers when they are elements of a structure array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

I want to check if the string SET_NAME is the name of an existing set, and if so, SET1 will point to the address of that set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char set[16];

int main(){

    char set_name[5] = {'0'};
    char *set1;
    int i;

    set_name[0] = 'S';
    set_name[1] = 'E';
    set_name[2] = 'T';
    set_name[3] = 'B';

    set SETA = {'0'};
    set SETB = {'0'};
    set SETC = {'0'};
    set SETD = {'0'};
    
    struct{
        char *name;
        set *myset;
    }sets[]={
    {"SETA", &SETA}, 
    {"SETB", &SETB},
    {"SETC", &SETC},
    {"SETD", &SETD}
    };  
    
    for(i=0; i < 4;i++){
        if(strcmp(set_name, sets[i].name)==0){
            set1 = sets[i].myset;
            printf("the set is found!\n%s\n", set_name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not work, probably due to incorrect use of elements in the structure.
The compiler writes to me like this:
assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
set1 = sets[i].myset;
and also-
warning: initializer element is not computable at load time [-Wpedantic]
{"SETD", &SETD},
for each element in the array.
I'm trying to fix and don't understand where my error is.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler give you errors and warnings for this with line numbers?

Comment: Your errors are coming from these `set_name[0] = {'S'};`. It's a char array, you need to assign each index a char value. ie `set_name[0] = 'S';`. And you should probably increase the size of `set_name` to 5 so you have room for a null terminating character `'\0'`. There are other issues with your code, but fixing that is a good start.

Comment: I corrected as you wrote, but the compiler warns again about the errors I wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never hide arrays or pointers behind `typedef`s
2. Your string `set_name` is too short. It has to be 5 characters long to accommodate null terminating character as well
3. `set_name[0] = {'S'};` makes no sense. If you want to assign a char to the particular element of the array do not use brackets.
4. `set SETA = {'0'};` it will initialize `SETA` with character `'0'` as a first element and zeroes the rest.
5. `&SETA` has the wrong type (pointer to array of 16 chars, not pointer to char)

After some amendments:

```
#define SETLENGTH 16

int main(){

    char set_name[] = "SETB";
    char *set1;
    int i;

    char SETA[SETLENGTH] = "";
    char SETB[SETLENGTH] = "";    
    char SETC[SETLENGTH] = "";    
    char SETD[SETLENGTH] = "";    

    struct{
        char *name;
        char *myset;
    }sets[]={
    {"SETA", SETA}, 
    {"SETB", SETB},
    {"SETC", SETC},
    {"SETD", SETD}
    };  
    
    for(i=0; i < 4;i++){
        if(strcmp(set_name, sets[i].name)==0){
            set1 = sets[i].myset;
            printf("the set is found!\n%s\n", set_name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! but the compiler still warns - warning: initializer element is not computable at load time [-Wpedantic]
     {"SETD", SETD}
I do not know why.

Comment: @Chanif forget about pedantic. It compiles using very old C (over 30y old) standard. Learn something more modern. Forget ANSI C

Comment: I'm a student and these are part of the requirements, there must be no warnings in the code, so I'm trying to fix it

Comment: @Chanif I do not see any warnings https://godbolt.org/z/69cMszYTj

Comment: @Chanif this warning is tagged "pedantic" for a reason. One standard or another says that initializer elements have to be constants - but this compiler is perfectly able of compiling ones that are not constants - so it compiles it anyway, and warns you "hey by the way this is non-standard". You can turn off "pedantic" warnings by adding the option "-Wno-pedantic" I believe

Comment: @Chanif if you have to have the warning turned on and fix it, because of the requirements - then you have to fill in the `sets` array with code, not in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

A minimal fix to the original code is:

```
typedef char set[16];    // instead of "unsigned char"
```

and

```
set1 = *sets[i].myset;   // added the "*" operator
```

because `sets[i].myset` is a pointer to `char[16]`, so applying `*` operator gets you a `char[16]` which you can then have `set1` point to the decay of.

The other answer implicitly suggests redesigning the code to not use pointers to `char[16]` at all; which is more of a stylistic decision. One advantage of this is the compiler can enforce array size checking for you, although the flip side is that using this technique requires understanding arrays and pointers thoroughly !

---

The warning `initializer element is not computable at load time` refers to a restriction in C89 that was fixed in C99, so you can make it go away by setting your compiler to C99 or later mode.  In C89 the contents of a `{ }` initializer had to be constant expressions, e.g. values of variables, or addresses of local variables could not be used.

If you are forced to write in C89 mode then you can replace the initializer by a series of assignment expressions for each element .